# How to deploy a jupyter notebook app for near zero cost

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, hosting

I have a searchable database for which I built a Jupyter notebook based interface for a friend with minimal programming skills. The db and index are ~10GB on disk. This setup currently lives on a personal machine, but I would like to make it available to him on an as-needed basis from some third-party host.

This could be deployed to a 24/7 AWS instance but it will be only used once in a while and thus be cost inefficient.

Do any services exist which have as-needed instances which are very easy to turn on and off (in consideration of my friend's technical comfort level) that would be good hosts for such a notebook?

Comment: You could host it on a raspberry pi and add a port forwarding rule to your router setup

Comment: It's on a NUC at the moment but my connection is bad enough that I'm looking for a slightly more reliable option. Thanks though!